# Is it possible to change the entire array element in JavaScript to number type?

Tags: javascript

Ex)

```
const a = ['1' , '2' , '3']
```

When there is an array called ,
is there a way to change it all at once without looping?

i want result [1,2,3]

Comment: You would have to loop, unless there was an asynchronous way.

Comment: No, there has to be a loop. Though you have several different loops at your disposal, whether structured, functional or recursive.

Comment: `['1' , '2' , '3'].map(n => +n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of, but not really.

The best approach is likely to do an array map as such:

```
const a = ['1' , '2' , '3'];
const b = a.map(function(i) {return Number(i);});
```

The advantage to mapping is that it theoretically can be done in parallel instead of sequentially. However, JavaScript's particular implementation doesn't really allow for this because JS uses a single thread and a scheduler instead of a truly multi-threaded approach.

However, using mapping is a cleaner and better approach because if some day JavaScript implements multithreading, the `map()` method could theoretically be changed to go multithreaded. If that was ever done, your code would already benefit from that (very unlikely) change.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way possible.

Read more about Array.map() here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

It's very simple. You just have to do this:-

```js
a.map(strN => (!isNaN(strN)) ? Number(strN) : strN)
```

*Notice: This will return the same value if the string isn't a number.